# SQL Query Creates Duplicated Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

My task is to produce a report that shows the on time delivery of products to consumers. In essence I have achieved this. However, as you will see only some of the data is accurate.

Here is our test case: we have a sales order number '12312.' This sales order has had 5 partial shipments made (200 pieces each). The result is shown below from our DUE_DTS table.

[Due Dates table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0hgX.jpg)

The following code gives me the information I need (excluding due date information) to show the packing details of the 5 shipments:

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE ( 
                         CUSTNAME char(35), 
                         SONO char(10), 
                         INVDATE date, 
                         PACKLISTNO char(10), 
                         PART_NO char(25), 
                         SOBALANCE numeric(9,2)
                    )

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT DISTINCT c.CUSTNAME, s.SONO, p.INVDATE, p.PACKLISTNO, i.PART_NO, q.SOBALANCE
FROM [manex].[dbo].[SODETAIL] 
INNER JOIN [manex].[dbo].[SOMAIN] s ON s.SONO = SODETAIL.SONO
INNER JOIN [manex].[dbo].[CUSTOMER] c ON c.CUSTNO = s.CUSTNO
INNER JOIN [manex].[dbo].[INVENTOR] i ON i.UNIQ_KEY = SODETAIL.UNIQ_KEY
INNER JOIN [manex].[dbo].[DUE_DTS] d ON d.SONO = s.SONO
INNER JOIN [manex].[dbo].[PLMAIN] p ON p.SONO = s.SONO
INNER JOIN [manex].[dbo].[PLDETAIL] q ON q.PACKLISTNO = p.PACKLISTNO
WHERE s.SONO LIKE '%12312'

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Here is a screenshot of the results from running this query:

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXkDg.jpg)

Now is when it should be time to join my due dates table (adding in the appropriate column(s) to my table definition and select statement) and make `DATEDIFF` comparisons to determine if shipments were on time or late. However, once I reference the due dates table, each of the 5 shipments is compared to all 5 dates in the due dates table, resulting in 25 rows. The only linking column `DUE_DTS` has is the `SONO` column. I've tried using `DISTINCT` and variations of the group by clause without success.

I've put enough together myself to figure joining the `DUE_DTS` table on `SONO` must be causing this to happen, as there are 5 instances of that value in the table (making it not unique) and a join should be based on a unique column. Is there a workaround for something like this?

Comment: Why the mysql tag?

Comment: Yeah, this is ms sql server, not mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use additional fields to join the records and reduce the results. You may need to link SONO to SODETAIL to DUE_DTS because the dates are tied to the items, not to the SONO.